# Avalonia - Is it possible to have a scrollable tool tip?

Tags: c#, xaml, tooltip, avalonia

I have a rich tooltip with a custom control.
The custom control contains a scollviewer and I would like this to be scrollable with the mouse wheel, when the tooltip is shown.

The UserControl itself is fine and scrolling works, if shown in a normal view.

```
<ItemsControl Items="{Binding AllCards}" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CardControl ToolTip.Placement="Right"
                         ToolTip.ShowDelay="10">
                <ToolTip.Tip>
                    <UserControl Content="{Binding Details}" MaxHeight="500"/>
                </ToolTip.Tip>
            </CardControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Excerpt of the user control shown in the tooltip.

```
<UserControl>
  ...

    <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="800">
        <ItemsControl Items="{Binding HitList}" Margin="0,5,15,0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to scroll `ToolTip` content because [it cannot receive focus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/tooltip-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#what-is-a-tooltip). More appropriate control for this purpose would be a `Popup`, it has the same default looks and it will not close when you hover your mouse over.